# Replace first occurrence of forward slash

Tags: java

I have the following String 'user/hello' ,'example/first' , 'stackoverflow/login' etc

I want to modify it as follows user/1/hello, example/1/first , stackoverflow/1/login.

I want to replace first '/' with '/1/'

I tried replaceFirst but I am not able to get the expected result.

```
String temp = "user/hello";
temp.replaceFirst("/","/1/");
```

Comment: Post what you tried then and what didn't work.

Comment: `String`s are immutable in Java, `replaceFirst` returns the new result, so you need to have `temp = temp.replaceFirst("/","/1/");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of replaceFirst back to `temp`

```
String temp = "user/hello";
temp = temp.replaceFirst("/","/1/");
```